# Passing multidimensional array by reference in C

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int *app[][20]) {
    int i, j;
    for (i =0; i< 20; i++){
        for (j=0; j<20; j++){
            *app[i][j] = i;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
  int app[20][20];
  int i, j;
  f(&app);
    for (i =0; i< 20; i++){
        for (j=0; j<20; j++){
            printf("i %d, j%d  val= %d\n", i, j, app[i][j]);
        }
    }

  return 0;
}
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here? I don't get any error, but there is a segmentation fault and I don't know why.

```
te.c:15:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘f’ from incompatible pointer type
   f(&app);
     ^
te.c:3:6: note: expected ‘int * (*)[20]’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[20][20]’
 void f(int *app[][20]) {
```

Comment: why are you trying to run code that does not cleanly compile?

Comment: I ignored it as it was a warning and tried to run. 
Since it was a pointer error, it was bound to be a seg. fault. that's when I asked this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
void f(int *app[][20]) { /* a 2d array of pointers to int */
```

should be

```
void f(int app[][20]) { /* a pointer to an array of 20 int's */
```

or

```
void f(int (*app)[20]) { /* a pointer to an array of 20 int's */
```

---

```
*app[i][j] = i;
```

should be

```
app[i][j] = i; /* you don't need to dereference */
```

---

```
f(&app);
```

should be

```
f(app);
```

Comment: Question of curiosity: When passing a value as a pointer to a function we do `f(&i)` and  use it as `void f (int *i)`. Why not here?

Comment: When you pass an `int` to a function using `int i; f(i);` you are passing the value, when you use `int i; f(&i);` you are passing a reference to the variable

Comment: Why can't we pass by reference here?

Comment: Because an array decays into a pointer when is passed to a function, in other words: `int a[][20];` decays into `int (*a)[20];` (a pointer to an array of 20 `int`'s)

Answer (score 2):

```
void f(int *app[][20])
```

should be

```
void f(int app[][20])
```

and the call should be like

```
f(app);
```

The changes done in the function `f()` is visible in `main()`
You can access the array in function `f()` like `app[i][j]`

Answer (score 0):

the following code correctly implements the definition and passing of a pointer to the 'app[][]' array to function 'f'

Notice the replacement of the 'magic' numbers
with #define'd values

Notice the proper use of prototypes.
This will become very important as the projects become larger and consist of multiple files.  Although when the project becomes multiple files, then each source file should have its' own header file that contains the prototypes for that source file

The code cleanly compiles and runs correctly

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS (20)
#define COLS (20)

void f(int app[][COLS]);


int main(void) 
{
    int app[ROWS][COLS];
    int i, j;

    f(app);
        
    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            printf("i %d, j%d  val= %d\n", i, j, app[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void f(int app[][COLS]) 
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            app[i][j] = i;
        }
    }
}
```